# How can i know what is the release of osCommerce?

Tags: oscommerce

how can i know what is the release of osCommerce? is the release written in any file of the package?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

```
includes/application_top.php
```

there should be something like:

```
// define the project version
  define('PROJECT_VERSION', 'osCommerce 2.2-MS2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Oscommerce version is also shown in Admin, using Server Info in Tools. It shows at the top of the server info page....cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you look into 2.3.3 oscommerce version code.

// define the project version --- obsolete, now retrieved with tep_get_version()
  define('PROJECT_VERSION', 'osCommerce Online Merchant v2.3');

in application_top.php above line states that  define('PROJECT_VERSION', 'osCommerce Online Merchant v2.3'); is obsolete

This is what is expected
$current_version = tep_get_version();

echo $current_version;

Look into tep_get_version(); code 
version is actually in DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'includes/version.php'

2.3.3